# ALAssetsLibrary and Location Services in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, alassetslibrary

I'm in the process of upgrading one of my apps to support `iOS6` and `iPhone5`. In the previous version, I had to prompt the user to enable Location Services in order to display photos using the `ALAssetsLibrary`. I've noticed that in iOS 6, I can disable location services and it still displays all images correctly. Is this something that has changed in  `iOS6`. The documentation states that you still need `Location Services` enabled but the documentation also states that it's for `iOS4` and above.  I can't find any mention regarding `iOS6` specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change is (more or less) documented in the [iOS SDK Release Notes for iOS 6](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html):

> In iOS 6, there are improved privacy controls for Calendar, Reminders,
>   Contacts, and Photos. Users will see access dialogs when an app tries
>   to access any of those data types. The user can switch access on and
>   off in Settings > Privacy.

Also, the ALAssetsLibrary has a new method [authorizationStatus](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722-CH1-SW58), which is available since iOS 6.

In iOS 5, there was no privacy setting for Photos, and the user had to allow access to Location Services because a photo might contain location data. This was (I think) annoying and confusing, and I am glad that it is fixed in iOS 6.